# Log4j2: Configuration with different log level based on system property

Tags: log4j2

I use log4j2 in my application and have an xml configuration file. There are multiple loggers configured in this file. I would like to set the level for those loggers based on the value of some system property. I know that I can access system properties like this `${sys:property}`. But I guess I also need to add some conditional logic to the configuration, as I want something like this:

```
if (${sys:property}=="value") {
    <Logger name=logger.name level="ERROR">
} else {
    <Logger name=logger.name level="INFO">    
}
```

How can I add such conditional logic to the log4j2 configuration?

Comment: Reading another configuration file may be good. 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.5/faq.html#reconfig_from_code
By the way, for what?

Comment: @OtsukiTakaya thanks for the hint. I used the idea of just creating another configuration and separating them on the java-level.

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't set a system property to the level you want? E.g. property name "Log4j2LogLevel" with value "DEBUG"
If you can do this then you can just use the lookup directly in the logger config: 
E.g. `<Root level="${sys:Log4j2LogLevel}">`

Comment: @D.B. In my specific case it's not as applicable as the first commented idea because I have multiple loggers which may assume different levels based on an system property and also I didn't want to add another system property to the system. In general your idea also sounds like a possible solution imo.